# How to draw Aqua backgrounds like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, tutorial

Can please somebody tell me how to draw a background like this? The gradient in the background is not a big deal, but the lines...

[image]

I guess it can be done in Photoshop or some other tool. Maybe there is a good "How to/Tutorial" somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you Google "Photoshop Aqua Background tutorial" You'll find dozens of tutorials.

Comment: They're translucent ovals with linear gradients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: [Create a aqua style wallpaper in Photoshop](http://www.webeverythings.com/photoshop/create-a-aqua-style-wallpaper-in-photoshop/)

Open new document in Photoshop with the size of 1600px X 1200px and background color is #4990c1.
first choose foreground color white then Select the pen tool and draw like this:

[image]

Decrease fill to 30%

[image]

Now right click on layer then go to blending options:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Create a new layer and then select both layer and right click merge layers:

[image]

Now add layer mask:

[image]

Now choose foreground color is white and background color is black. Then select gradient tool and choose radial gradient:

[image]

Draw like this:

[image]

Now select pen tool then draw like this:

[image]

make all setting like first one.
Then it’s look like this:

[image]

Make copy same layers and scale the size and position of the layer. Try like this:

[image]

Now make new layer and select gradient tool and draw center to right. then change layer option to overlay and change layer opacity to 30%. It’s look like this.
It’s final result:

[image]

Comment: In addition to this, some of the objects appear to have their gradient "folded over." This is achieved by the extra step of using the warp tool.